# include date format into another variable in bash

Tags: bash, variables, syntax

I am having some difficulties to figure a syntax as when including my date's variable into another one.

Here is the script snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash -x


DAY=$(date +%d-%m-%y)
YESTERDAY=$(date -d "-1 days" +"%d-%m-%Y")
FILE=/tmp/${YESTERDAY}/*
OUTPUT="/tmp/count_${YESTERDAY}.log"

        for i in $FILE
        do
        grep -oP "(?<=<TEST>).*?(?=</TEST>)" ${i} >> ${OUTPUT}; 
        done
```

output:

```
grep: /tmp/06-07-2015/*: No such file or directory
```

If I am setting up manually the variable like:

```
FILE="/tmp/06-07-15/*"
```

then the it work out;

Thank you for your help and suggestion :)

AL

Comment: does `/tmp/06-07-2015/` directory exist? It is a bit unclear what you are asking here

Comment: That error from `grep` means that the glob `/tmp/06-07-2015/*` failed to expand to any files (and remained unexpanded) which means the directory `/tmp/06-07-2015` either didn't exist or was empty.

Comment: Yes, this directory exist and files are present. this is why I am struggling.. :(

Comment: We cannot debug for you. Either provide more information or this will be closed as "unclear what you are asking" or "why isn't this code working?"

Comment: ok. If I do remove the date's variable part of the variable FILE; then it works and the loop expand correctly the files. I need to set manually the FILE path ex: FILE="/tmp/06-07-15"

Comment: DAY=$(date +%d-%m-%y)
    #YESTERDAY=$(date -d "-1 days" +"%d-%m-%Y")
    FILE=/tmp/06-07-15/*
    OUTPUT="/tmp/count_${YESTERDAY}.log"

            for i in $FILE
            do
            ls -al ${i}
            done

Comment: You do realize that `06-07-2015` and `06-07-15` are two different directory names, right? `YESTERDAY` is set with `%Y`, not `%y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong specifier for the year when you set the value of `YESTERDAY`; `%Y` puts the 4-digit year in the string, not the 2-digit year that your directory seems to use. Change that line to

```
YESTERDAY=$(date -d "-1 days" +"%d-%m-%y")
```